# Cannot import dynamically installed python module

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am dynamically installing code during the runtime of a script by directly importing the pip module and installing a requirements.txt:

```
import pip
import site
import sys

# since I'm installing with --user, packages should be installed here,
# so make sure it's on the path
sys.path.insert(0, site.USER_SITE)

pip.main(["install", "--user", "package1"])
import package1
```

The package installs without error, but `import package1` fails. If I quit the script and run it again without doing the install (since it's already been installed), it works just fine.

I've also double checked that the `site.USER_SITE` is where package1 was installed. Everything is on sys.path, but I still can't import it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this was a fast turnaround. I've been trying to figure this one out for a few days and finally came up with my answer a few minutes after asking on here.

If a path that does not yet exist is added to `sys.path`, it doesn't seem like it will ever be checked again when importing modules, even if it exists at a later point (or at least in python 2.7).

In my testing, `site.USER_SITE` didn't exist when I added it to `sys.path`. If I first made sure that that directory exists, then everything works how you would think it should:

```
import os
import pip
import site
import sys

# this makes it work
if not os.path.exists(site.USER_SITE):
    os.makedirs(site.USER_SITE)

# since I'm installing with --user, packages should be installed here,
# so make sure it's on the path
sys.path.insert(0, site.USER_SITE)

pip.main(["install", "--user", "package1"])
import package1
```